# Laravel form select poulated by eloquent model

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am currently making an edit page for some data in my database, and on the edit page I am trying to make a Form::select which lists the people in my users table.

controller-which-makes-the-edit-view.php

```
<?php

class AdminController extends BaseController
{
    public $restful = true;

    public function getUpdatePage($id)
    {
        return View::make('data_edit')
        ->with('title', 'Rediger måling/oppgave')
        ->with('data', Routine::find($id))
        ->with('emp', Emp::lists('user_name', 'id'));
    }
```

data_edit.blade.php

```
{{ Form::label('emp', 'Ansatt') }}
{{ Form::select('emp', $emp, $data->emps->user_name) }}
```

Now my question is how would I go about making the default value for the select the person that saved the row which is currently being edited?

I do apologize if this already is answered, I couldn't seem to find it (neither here nor google).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `Form::select()` definition:

```
public function select($name, $list = array(), $selected = null, $options = array())
{
}
```

The third parameter is the item to be selected. You are currently passing

```
$data->emps->user_name
```

To it, but it depends on the data you have on `$emp`, because you must pass to it the array key, not the value.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for now (Laravel 5.3+), `::lists` is obsolete, use `::pluck` instead.